My kivy widgets are cramped together and I need them to have some distance
The following is a problem I have with the kivy module. When I created my first 3-4 widgets of the FirstScreen class - everything was fine, but after that the widgets started to occupy the same space that they used to, without expanding up. Maybe it's a problem of the ScrollView. There is no kv file
the widgets are shown here
from functools import partial

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager, NoTransition
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

class YogaApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.sm = ScreenManager(transition=NoTransition())
        self.sm.add_widget(FirstScreen(name='First'))
        self.sm.add_widget(SecondScreen(name='Second'))
        self.sm.add_widget(ThirdScreen(name='Third'))
        self.sm.add_widget(FourthScreen(name='Fourth'))
        self.sm.add_widget(FifthScreen(name='Fifth'))
        # self.sm.current = 'Second' # Для того чтобы тестировать шаблоны. УБРАТЬ ПОТОМ
        return self.sm
    def change_screen_manager(self, screen):
        self.sm.current = screen

class FirstScreen(Screen):
    """The first screen the user sees. It is the screen for creating a workout or a workout
    template. It also shows all of your created templates which you can click for the second
    screen to pop up
    """
    total_training_sessions = 0
    total_training_sessions_text = 'Всего тренировок: ' + str(total_training_sessions)
    # Это шаблоны тренировок
    templates = {}
    # А это все упражнения
    # exercises = []

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        """
        Creates all widgets and adds them on the first screen. Creates templates that
        are a button with the text of the name and the exercises of the template.
        It does so by extracting the template name and values from the dictionary 'templates'
        
        :param kwargs:
        """
        super(FirstScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.layout_root = ScrollView(do_scroll_x=False, do_scroll_y=True, size_hint=(1, None))
        self.layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical', size_hint=(1, 1))
        self.lbl1 = Label(text=self.total_training_sessions_text)
        # Кнопка, при нажатии которой откроется второй экран
        self.btn_create = Button(text='Создать Шаблон', on_press=partial(app.change_screen_manager, 'Second')) #Don't mind this. The partial function doesn't work
        # self.btn_create.bind(on_press= изменить sm.current на второй экран)
        self.lbl2 = Label(text='Шаблоны:')  # , pos_hint={'x': -0.42}

        self.layout.add_widget(self.lbl1)
        self.layout.add_widget(self.btn_create)
        self.layout.add_widget(self.lbl2)

        import os
        for filename in os.listdir('templates'):
            with open(os.path.join('templates', filename), 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
                self.lbl_name = Label(text = str(filename.replace('.txt', '')))
                self.layout.add_widget(self.lbl_name)
                k=0 #Считает кол-во упражнений в шаблоне
                while True:
                    exercise_info = file.readlines(2)
                    k+=1
                    if not exercise_info:
                        break
                    num_of_exercise, exercise = exercise_info
                    num_of_exercise = str(num_of_exercise.replace("\n", ""))
                    exercise = str(exercise.replace("\n", ""))
                    text_1 = str(k) + " - " + exercise + " x" + num_of_exercise
                    self.template_lbl = Label(text = text_1)
                    self.layout.add_widget(self.template_lbl)
                self.template_btn = Button() # will actually make the button when the problem is fixed
                    




        self.layout_root.add_widget(self.layout)
        self.add_widget(self.layout_root)
    def create_widgets(self):
        for template in self.templates:
            pass



class SecondScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs): # add template
        super(SecondScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.create_widgets() #ТОЖЕ УБРАТЬ

    def create_widgets(self):#, template):

        # for x in template.keys():
        #    name = str(x)
        name = 't1'
        layout_root = ScrollView(do_scroll_x=False, do_scroll_y=True, size_hint=(1, None))
        layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        lbl1 = Label(text=name)
        btn_rest = Button()
        btn_start = Button()
        # btn_cancel = CancelButton()
        # self.btn_cancel = Button(text='Отмена', on_press=app.sm.switch_to('First'))
        # self.ids['cancel'] = Button()
        # self.ids['layout'].add_widget(self.btn_start) НЕ РАБОТАЕТ
        # self.ids['layout'].add_widget(self.btn_rest)
        layout.add_widget(lbl1)
        layout.add_widget(btn_rest)
        layout.add_widget(btn_start)
        # layout.add_widget(btn_cancel)
        layout_root.add_widget(layout)
        self.add_widget(layout_root)




class ThirdScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ThirdScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.layout_root = ScrollView(do_scroll_x=False, do_scroll_y=True, size_hint=(1, None))
        self.layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        self.name_input = TextInput(text='Название Шаблона', multiline=False, size_hint = (0.8, None), height='100dp')


class FourthScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(FourthScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)


class FifthScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(FifthScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = YogaApp()
    app.run()


I have tried giving pos_hint = {'top': 1} to the first widget. Didn't work (probably should have expected that)
I thought that the BoxLayout doesn't occupy all of the space of the ScrollView, so I have given the BoxLayout size_hint = (1,1), but it didn't work
I have not tried anything else because I have no idea what's wrong with it

When you use a ScrollView, its child widget (BoxLayout in your case) must adjust its size to contain its children. The BoxLayout has a minimum_height property that calculates the minimum height of the BoxLayout that will contain all its children. So that can be used to set the height of the BoxLayout like this:
    self.layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical', size_hint=(1, None))
    self.layout.bind(minimum_height=self.layout.setter('height'))

Note the size_hint_y=None for the BoxLayout, which allows the height of the BoxLayout to be adjusted. The second line above actually does the adjusting of the height of the BoxLayout.
One other issue is that in order for the BoxLayout to calculate its minimum_height, its children must have known heights (i.e., you cannot use size_hint). An easy fix for that issue is to add size_hint_y=None, height=20 to each Widget that gets added to the BoxLayout.
Try making these changes to your code.

Thank you, it somewhat works. The widgets are not cramped and the ScrollView works fine, but the BoxLayout doesn't go to the top of the window. about 80% of the window is empty and the widgets are concentrated at the bottom (+ some widgets are out of the screen and are only accesible through the ScrollView). If I add more widgets the size proportions don't change, the new stuff is located even more outside the window (I still can scroll to them through the ScrollView). Any idea what is going on here and how to fix it?

You create the ScrollView with size_hint=(1, None), but you don't set its height. So the ScrollView ends up with its default height of 100. Try just removing the size_hint from the ScrollView, which leaves the default of size_hint=(1, 1).
